# Android - "ant test" with subdirectory

Tags: android, unit-testing, ant

I have all of my tests in my test project located in a `tests/` directory and everything in this directory is run when I call `ant test`.  The directory has a few subdirectories, such as `unit` and `functional`.  How can I tell `ant test` to only run tests in one of these subdirectories and ignore the others?

Answer (score 0):

In my setup i defined a separate Ant target for each type of test, and then made each target conditional on some property.

```
   <target name="performance" if="test.performance">
   </target>
```

Then at build time specify the required properties on the ant command line (-Dkey=value). If you have allot of different packages to be tested independently consider defining properties in a properties file which you load in your build file.

let me know if you have any questions

Comment: What do you have inside the target?  Do you just have an `ant` tag that calls `ant test`?  I kind of would like more detail here in terms of what the target looks like and what exactly you are calling with the -D flag.